# How many sets of three integers between 1 and 20 are possible if no two consecutive integers are to be in a set?

Tags: combinatorics

Total number of sets is $$\begin{pmatrix}20\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
I tried to classify  sets having two consecutive integers in them into three parts

1. having either 1 or 20
2. having both 1 and 20
3. not having both 1 and 20

Trying the first : took permutation first and divided it by 3! to get combination 
(probably went there wrong)$$ \frac{2 *18 *16}{3!}  $$
what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways we can select three numbers from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$ so that no two of them are consecutive is the number of ways we can arrange $17$ blue and $3$ green balls so that no two of the green balls are consecutive.

Line up $17$ blue balls in a row.  This creates $18$ spaces, $16$ between successive blue balls and two at the ends of the row.

[image: blue_balls]

To ensure that no two of the green balls are consecutive, we choose three of these $18$ spaces in which to insert a green ball, which can be done in 
$$\binom{18}{3}$$
ways.  For instance, if we choose the first, seventh, and eleventh spaces, we obtain the arrangement

[image: blue_and_green_balls]

Once the green balls have been placed, we number the balls from left to right. The numbers on the green balls are the desired subset of three numbers from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$ since no two of those numbers are consecutive.  In the example illustrated above, those nonconsecutive numbers are $1, 8, 13$.

Answer (score 3):

You started out right, there are $\binom{20}{3}$ sets.  Now we have to subtract the number of sets with two consecutive numbers.  There are $19$ pairs of consecutive numbers and for each of these, we have $18$ choices for the third number, so that makes $19\cdot18$.  However, if a set has $3$ consecutive numbers, we've subtracted it twice, and so we have to add these $18$ sets back in.  Altogether, we have $$\binom{20}{3}-19\cdot18+18$$

You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle