# To find the number of sets of three integers between 1 and 20 are possible if no two consecutive integers are to be in a set?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was doing the following problem.

How many sets of three integers between 1 and 20 are possible if no two consecutive
integers are to be in a set?

I got the following link of the same question, but in the second answer I am unable to get the lines

**"However, if a set has 3 consecutive numbers, we've subtracted it twice, and so we have to add these 18 sets back in."**

[How many sets of three integers between 1 and 20 are possible if no two consecutive integers are to be in a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465771/how-many-sets-of-three-integers-between-1-and-20-are-possible-if-no-two-consecut)

Can anyone explain how the question was solved? It will of great help. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: By "numbers between 1 and 20" you mean numbers from the set 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, right? Or do you consider 1 and 20 to be "between 1 and 20"?

Comment: Yeah. In the link provided, the answer includes 1 and 20, and that created confusion. If in question it is mentioned that between 1 and 20, it means we have to omit 1 and 20. I feel so. Am I right?

Comment: If you want to include 1 and 20 it's customary to write "between 1 and 20, inclusive" for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Throughout this answer I'm going to be referring to the numbers in order, I'd like to point out that what I mean is the order when the set is ordered from least to greatest. I'm aware that the order doesn't matter for the counting.

If we pick three numbers, there are two ways that two of the numbers can be consecutive. The first two can be consecutive or the second two can be consecutive, or potentially both.

So, if we generate all of the sets of three numbers, then in order to get the number of sets without any consecutive numbers, we have to subtract out the cases where either the first two numbers were consecutive or the second two numbers were consecutive. But if we do this, then any case where all three numbers are consecutive will be subtracted out twice, since it's in both sets. So now we need to add it back in once so we've added it twice and subtracted it twice.

Symbolically we can represent this concept like this: if $A$ is the set of all combinations of three numbers from $1$ to $20$ with no consecutive numbers, $B$ is the set of all possible combinations, and $C$ is the set of combinations with some consecutive numbers. Also let $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the sets of combinations where the first and second pairs of numbers are consecutive.

Because $A$ and $C$ can have no shared members and $B = A \cup C$, we have that $|B| = |A| + |C|$, so $|A| = |B| - |C|$. Now because $C = C_1 \cup C_2$, we have $|C| = |C_1| + |C_2| - |C_1 \cap C_2|$, so $|A| = |B| - |C_1| - |C_2| + |C_1 \cap C_2|$.

Hope this helps!